# How to create multiple son directories using mkdir in freeBSD?

Tags: directory, freebsd, mkdir

I am using mkdir to create directories under FreeBSD 10.2. I know -p option enables me to create a/b/c very easily (mkdir -p a/b/c). Now I want a to have two son directories b and c(a/c,a/b). Is it possible to do that by using only one mkdir command ? I have searched the net and found :

```
 mkdir -p project/{lib/ext,bin,src,doc/{html,info,pdf},demo/stat/a}
```

which claims to generate the following result:

```
project/
project/lib/ext
project/bin
project/src
project/doc/html
project/doc/info
project/doc/pdf
project/demo/stat/a
```

However, this doesn't work in FreeBSD. Anybody can explain ? Thanks

Comment: I believe the brace expansions are the responsibility of the shell. You need to investigate the shell you are using, or switch to the same shell used in the example you found.

Comment: Stumbled upon this too: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/why-does-this-command-have-two-very-different-results.57800/

Answer (score 1):

It works fine here (FreeBSD 10.2-STABLE amd64) using the default `tcsh` shell;

```
> mkdir -p project/{lib/ext,bin,src,doc/{html,info,pdf},demo/stat/a}
> find .
.
./project
./project/lib
./project/lib/ext
./project/bin
./project/src
./project/doc
./project/doc/html
./project/doc/info
./project/doc/pdf
./project/demo
./project/demo/stat
./project/demo/stat/a
```

It does *not* work in the Bourne shell, `sh`.